# How do I set margins with NReco.PdfGenerator?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, margins

I succeeded at changing many settings with NReco.PDFGenerator, but I do not understand how to set the margins.  I found a `.Margins` option, yet it wants the type to be `PageMargins`.  Below are some things I tried. How do I set the top, left, bottom, and right margins?

```
HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
pdfConverter.Size = PageSize.Letter;
pdfConverter.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
pdfConverter.Zoom = 1F;
pdfConverter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--encoding UTF-8";

// What I tried...
pdfConverter.Margins = (PageMargins)1;    // can't caste
pdfConverter.Margins = PageMargins.????;  // no appropriate methods
pdfConverter.Margins = 1;                 // wrong type
pdfConverter.Margins = "1";               // wrong type
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the margins:

```
pdfConverter.Margins = new PageMargins {Top = 1, Bottom = 1, Left = 1, Right = 1}
```

or

```
var margins = new PageMargins();

margins.Top = 1;
margins.Bottom = 1;
margins.Left= 1;
margins.Right= 1;

pdfConverter.Margins = margins;
```

(Assuming: `using NReco.PdfGenerator;`)

They do the same thing, ie will set all the margins to 1mm.
You can read more here: http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/